# RAM compatibility with Intel P45 chipset

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have an Asus P5QC motherboard, with Intel P45 chipset, which supports DDR2 and DDR3 RAM. I want to use two 4GB sticks to have 8GB of RAM.

I read that there are some sticks that don't work with that motherboard. For example, [asus p5qc unsolvable problem](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/309026-30-asus-p5qc-unsolvable-problem), says that the Intel P45 chipset will not support high density, 512MB sticks.  On the other hand, [MythBUSTED Density FACTS Low-Density vs High-Density](http://www.ebay.com/gds/MythBUSTED-Density-FACTS-Low-Density-vs-High-Density-/10000000003939852/g.html) says that isn't true.

Every RAM module that I found is made of 512MB chips.  What is the truth about any compatibility issues between high-density RAM and the P45 chipset?

Comment: Memorys I think will work:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/patriot-2x4-gb-8gb-kit-pc3-10600-1333-mhz/231464874592?_trksid=p2047675.c100011.m1850&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D28808%26meid%3D70e653eb3a6446eb8f6b5e38552c3c9b%26pid%3D100011%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D10%26sd%3D231461280828

Comment: Another one: http://www.crucial.com/ProductDisplay?displayCompatibleLogo=1&urlRequestType=Base&catalogId=10151&productId=11818&externalPartNumber=CT4056090&urlLangId=-1&scanId=7D42D74931D926C3&langId=-1&storeId=10151

Comment: Questions seeking purchase advice are generally off-topic.  However, I think this question really deals more with the veracity of the claim that high density RAM is incompatible with the P45 chipset.  That is a technology question that I would think is on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK its the datasheet that is outdated and does not mention 2Gbit DDR3 chips. In reality I think they do work fine on most Core 2 chipsets (including even on P35). What is funny is that the [Mobile Intel 4 Series Express Chipset Family Datasheet](http://www.intel.com/assets/PDF/datasheet/320122.pdf) was updated to mention them, but most of the desktop chipset datasheets wasn't.

There is actually a good way to determine the maximum DDR3 DRAM capacity of a Intel memory controller (with the exception of 8Gbit DDR3), and that is to look at the number of memory address lines. If the address lines only goes to A14 for example like with most of the Core 2 chipsets, than only up to 2Gbit DDR3 can be supported (4Gbit DDR3 would require an extra A15 address line).